# Team Foundation Server-SDK Java API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, java

Is there any sites that can help me with Team Foundation Server SDK Java API with examples other than its own documentation?? I used  sample snippets from Team Foundation Server SDK itself and it helped a little with importing from server but need commit and update options through Java Api. it will be greatly appreciated if someone show me some referral sites, I need API functionality not any other workaround or choices :)

Comment: There is very little information about the tfs java sdk. The sdk zip file contains a javadoc but the comments only help so much. For most problems I've had to look up the .net sdk documentation and guess how to translate that to java. Unfortunately there are whole classes that exist in .net but not in java and vice versa. Sometimes I've even had to look at the bytecode to know what's going on.